Two or more Parallel Connection of 48V 300Ah Battery
I want to know the wire size of bus bar to hybrid inverter. The bus bar is connected with parallel connection of 300Ah(48V) batteries- 4Nos.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
